# Only Internet explorer doesn't allow my code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with Internet Explorer and HTML code. In Chrome, Edge and Firefox all works fine, but in Internet Explorer I have this problem displayed in the picture below:

The initial state,
[image]

and when I click the plus button

[image]

instead of

[image]

I found where the error is located, it is in datatable javascript:

```
data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
    var user;
    var s="";
    for (user in row.users)
    s += '<span class="tag label label-info"><span>'+row.users[user]+'</span><a>'
    +'<i id="deleteUserFleet" data-toggle="modal" data-application="'+row.application+'" data-fleet="'+row.idFleet+'" data-id="'+row.users[user]+'" data-target="#deleteUserFleetModal" class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a></span>';
    return s;
}
```

If I use return 'hello' all works fine, but there is an error in my above code that only Internet Explorer found. Do you know what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: You need to share the error, too.

Comment: There aren't error in tomcat or debug mode window, I.E. shows the page as above instead of correct format

Comment: nothing shows up in the IE developer tools console tab?

Comment: It's possible make a JsFiddle?

Comment: It's very hard, there are angularjs, datatables, web services. As you can see the first for cycle goes fine, the second return error.

Comment: without a propper manner, it will be a shoot in the dark. A wild guess I should ask to you put a if(row.users != null ) before the For, if it works, I should bet at lottery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For in loops work better semantically with **object keys** . For **arrays** you should use a regular for loop for this operation .

**Example**

```
for(var user = 0 ; user < row.users.length; user++){
// your code here
}
```

hope this helps .

Answer (score -2):

No need to worry about it. very few peoples are using  internet Explorer today (less than 10% peoples worldwide).

So, my suggestion is, you should create a code which all letest browser can run.

**if you still want to solve this problem i will recommend you to go *[w3school](http://w3schools.com)* and see which tag supports  ie**

Comment: a lot of users still use IE and a lot of clients require support for it so your answer is not really useful. also, it's more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: i agree. but when you look at the statistics, there is clearly mentioned that very few people using IE. according to statistics (april 2016) only 5.8 % peoples using IE ,70.4 % peoples are using chrome,17.5 % are using firefox .